# JavaScript shells - what is the difference

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_shells lists quite a few shells. What is there to choose between them.

Comment: I feel dumb, I didn't even know these things existed.  Going to have to try one of them next time I'm doing js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the command line tool in firebug to test snippets, there is an option "larger command line" for multiline code, so be sure to enable it. CTRL+SHIFT+L is the shortcut for opening the command line panel.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rhino Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell) is not on the list, but pretty cool, if you want to write your business logic and explore data.